# Selecting min id

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple relation in which category and subcategories are differentiated by parent_id and category has a parent_id 0 and subcategory has category_id as its parent_id.What i want to do is to select first subcategory of a first category.

for this i am using

> SELECT cat_id FROM member_product_cat WHERE cat_parent_id !=0 HAVING
>   cat_parent_id=min(cat_parent_id) LIMIT 1

but it gives me an error.I know i can do the same by

> SELECT cat_id FROM member_product_cat WHERE cat_parent_id=(Select
>   min(cat_parent_id) from member_product_cat where cat_parent_id !=0)
>   LIMIT 1

But what is wrong in my first approach?isnt it for this we have having clause?.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: What is the error ? The error log is always the key ...

Comment: SQL Error : 1054 Unknown column 'cat_parent_id' in 'having clause'
this is the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions.  So you do not need HAVING there at all.

Comment: so isnt it what i am doing here?i am using having with an aggergrate function.Or you mean i can use it like having min(id)=2 or something

Comment: SELECT column_name, aggregate_function(column_name)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING aggregate_function(column_name) operator value                                 The above the the standard template of where HAVING is used.

Comment: @techie_28, In Relational Algebra we have Select and others,  and your where is just a Select. Your aim is just to select a specific tuples and out of that tuple you picked cat_id. So is there anything really aggregate here. And note that WHERE is not followed by HAVING .. WHERE is conditional statement already.

Comment: I cant really do not understand HAVING here.I am confused.Care to clarify please?Anyone?

Comment: Just take it that HAVING followed after GROUP BY. And  your case you are not grouping at all, so there is no need of HAVING there.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT cat_id FROM member_product_cat WHERE cat_parent_id <> 0 where cat_parent_id=(SELECT min(cat_parent_id) from member_product_cat) LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is just

```
SELECT cat_id FROM member_product_cat 
WHERE cat_parent_id !=0 
ORDER BY cat_parent_id, cat_id LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `having` without `group by` even with an aggregate function in place, the `having` clause somewhat acts like a `where` clause..

A quick dive into the docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

*Quoting:*

`Standard SQL does not permit the HAVING clause to name any column not found in the GROUP BY clause unless it is enclosed in an aggregate function. MySQL permits the use of such columns to simplify calculations. This extension assumes that the nongrouped columns will have the same group-wise values. Otherwise, the result is indeterminate.`

I hope this will somehow help